# Need to convert the data type while inserting into the other table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 
(
    e_id    VARCHAR2(255),
    e_date  VARCHAR2(255),
    t_ref_num  VARCHAR2(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_tab1 PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1, '01-01-2000', 11);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2, '01-01-2001', 12);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (3, '01-01-2002', 13);

CREATE TABLE tab2 
(
    e_id       NUMBER(20),
    e_date     DATE,
    t_ref_num  NUMBER(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_tab2 PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);
```

I need to insert it into the tab2 table and need to convert the data type as per the tab2 table datatype. Because in tab1 table I will get always varchar datatype but while inserting into the tab2 table I have to typecast it and have to insert in proper datatype. How can I achieve this?

```
MERGE INTO tab2 tt
USING (SELECT
           e_id, e_date, _t_ref_num
       FROM tab1) t1 ON ( t2.e_id = t1.e_id )

WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE
        SET tt.e_date = t1.e_date,
            tt.t_ref_num = t1.t_ref_num

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (e_id, e_date, t_ref_num)
    VALUES (t1.e_id, t1.e_date, t1.t_ref_num);
```

I have to make the changes in the merge statement only.

Comment: You have just a little typoes. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a746a24d2802e730ba00e4afd879b7d). Btw, prefer storing a date value within a DATE type column.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot . I did all of them. The story so far seems handsome but the yielded product has got no sense. There are a few typoes as I've already told such as the column `t_ref_num` shouldn't be prefixed with `_`, the table `tab2` should be aliased decently, and a `TO_DATE` conversion is needed during the insertion provided the decision for storing a date column remains the same.

Comment: @Barbaros, thank you for not being ashamed to reply. Most of people wouldn't do that. As of your objections: `_` typo is a minor error (from my point of view). I don't quite understand what's wrong with `tab2` table's alias (`tt` in MERGE, right?), while `TO_DATE` shouldn't be used at all in INSERT because target column's datatype is VARCHAR2. If most of questions on SO looked like this one, I'd be more than happy.

Comment: Thank you too @Littlefoot I appreciate. There's a confusion for aliasing of `tab2`(somewhere `tt`,`t2`), indeed just one replace of `t2` to `tt` is enough. The target table(`tab2`)'s `e_date` column has `DATE` type not `VARCHAR2`...

Comment: Ah, I see it now! t2 vs. tt ... right, didn't even notice as I was writing my own MERGE and avoided it :) INSERT is into tab1 only; Vicky has already said that she (I guess it is a "she") doesn't know how to apply TO_DATE (while merging). OK, that's it, as far as I'm concerned. I hope you're doing well, BTW :)

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for the answer but I could not understand the conversation between you and Barbaros. Did I have post the wrong question? Because while posting this question I got a warning like your account can be blocked. Please be specific to the question you are asking but from my point of view, I have included all the possible things like test cases, my attempt, explanation.

Comment: As I said, your question is perfectly OK as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that in `USING` clause.

Setting date format (so that you'd know *what is what*; you don't have to do it):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Use `TO_DATE` with appropriate format mask on `e_date`; `t_ref_num` looks like an ordinary integer, so I'm just `TO_NUMBER`-ing it.

```
SQL> MERGE INTO tab2 tt
  2       USING (SELECT e_id,
  3                     TO_DATE (e_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') e_date,
  4                     TO_NUMBER (t_ref_num) t_ref_num
  5                FROM tab1) t1
  6          ON (tt.e_id = t1.e_id)
  7  WHEN MATCHED
  8  THEN
  9     UPDATE SET tt.e_date = t1.e_date, tt.t_ref_num = t1.t_ref_num
 10  WHEN NOT MATCHED
 11  THEN
 12     INSERT     (e_id, e_date, t_ref_num)
 13         VALUES (t1.e_id, t1.e_date, t1.t_ref_num);

3 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from tab2;

      E_ID E_DATE      T_REF_NUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         3 01.01.2002         13
         1 01.01.2000         11
         2 01.01.2001         12

SQL>
```